# What is the equivalent of this code in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

What is the equivalent of this code in PowerShell?

```
call opmnctl stopall >> %LOGFILE%
```

`LOGFILE` is a path to a file.

Comment: It may be urgent for *you*, but it's not urgent for *us*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalent:

```
$LOGFILE = path\log.txt
opmnctl stopall | out-file -append $LOGFILE
```

You can just do what you were doing, without the call as well:

```
opmnctl stopall >> $LOGFILE
```

Comment: what about this? What its equivalent in PowerShell?

 @echo off

SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\oracle\FRHome_1\dcm\bin\;D:\oracle\FRHome_1\opmn\BIN\;D:\oracle\FRHome_1

\opmn\BIN